# How to hide the accuracy circle on an MKMapView (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, mkmapview

I notice there's a ring around the blue dot on my `MKMapView` that seems to represent the accuracy of the location. I want to hide this ring, is this possible? If so how can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to create your own custom annotation and use that instead of the default one..